# vue components not updating laravel when change format folders LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

I work by laravel and vue.js,
I encountered a problem when I changed the file order in order to upload the project to the Internet,
The problem is that now when I update the vue files, nothing changes.
Please help from the experts here. Thank you

> Current files arrangement
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvIU5.png)

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.20.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "ladda": "^2.0.1",
    "npm-watch": "^0.9.0",
    "vee-validate": "^3.4.5",
    "vform": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-file-selector": "^0.6.0",
    "vue-recaptcha": "^1.3.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.1"
  },
  "name": "moqawala.ma",
  "description": "<p align=\"center\"><a href=\"https://laravel.com\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/art/master/logo-lockup/5%20SVG/2%20CMYK/1%20Full%20Color/laravel-logolockup-cmyk-red.svg\" width=\"400\"></a></p>",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "array.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "author": "Saad rifai",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: you changed the file order?

Comment: Yes, I took out the files inside the Public directory and modified my index.php

Comment: what has `package.json` to do with this? What did you modify in `index.php`? Did you configure the public dir correctly in apache for instance? So many questions

Comment: this what i modify in index.php

Comment: require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__ . '/bootstrap/app.php';

Comment: Now you notice that laravel mix saves files in Public folder

Comment: This is the reason why it does not happen in the browser

Comment: i have no clue what you edited. In essence you dont need to modify index.php at all. laravel mix saves files in public folder indeed since its required for these css/js variables to be available

Comment: I solved the problem after analyzing the code,
The problem is that Laravel Mix saves files in the public directory but is not called in the layout

Answer (score 0):

**I solved the problem after analyzing the code, The problem is that Laravel Mix saves files in the public directory but is not called in the layout**

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

TO

```
<script src="{{ asset('public/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```